# Grammar Check and sentencs

Tags: sentence-meaning

My boss replied me that "You misunderstood my point"
and he is right, I misunderstood him and then he continued writing to me explaining what he exactly want me to carry out the work.

So I want to reply him that sorry for misunderstanding and now I understand what you want me to carry out .

Is it OK to reply in such a way?

Comment: I would split the sentence into two and make a few adjustments so that it becomes _sorry for **the** misunderstanding. Now I understand what you want me to carry out_. You should also consider actually repeating what you now understand so that you can confirm that you have the right information. So you could say _sorry for **the** misunderstanding. Now I understand that you want me to 'fix the lights'_, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

- Sorry for the misunderstanding.
- Sorry that I couldn't understand you earlier.
- Sorry for my misunderstanding you.
- Pardon me, I misunderstood you back then.

Comment: @User26328 Sorry, forgot "**I**"